# "This Hangouts feature has not been enabled for your account. "

Tags: google-hangouts

Within Google app's I am unable to grant my users access to the Google Hangouts Chrome plugin.  I have checked my global domain settings as well as my settings for a user. But still users are unable to sign into Google Hangouts and receive this error message:

> "This Hangouts feature has not been enabled for your account. "

**See screenshot**
[image]

Answer (score 12):

The new Hangouts feature needs to be enabled by logging into the Admin console and going to

Google Apps -> Talk/Hangouts -> Advanced Settings

and select 'Enable the new Hangouts for users in this organizational unit'

Comment: Note: "Advanced Settings" appears as "Sharing Settings" and it may take some time (upwards of 15 minutes) to apply and you might have to re-log several times.

Answer (score 2):

To enable it click `Apps -> Talk` in the admin console there is a setting for enabling the new Hangouts.

Otherwise enable it in Apps Account. It's under `Settings > Services > Talk > Org Settings`.

Comment: I don't see these settings.  are you sure this is still how it is?

Answer (score 2):

Click on talk/hangouts anyway even if it shows that it is turned on.  Now click on Sharing Settings and you will see one more checkbox where you have to turn it on.